# Cannot break out of loop

Tags: c

I don't know why my code doesn't loop. My purpose is letting the user enter the correct number(1), otherwise the code will keep asking user to enter a number until the user enters '1'. After I run my code, if user enters an incorrect number, I don't know why my code doesn't ask the user to keep entering the number. Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   int answer =0;
   for( ; ; )
   {
      printf("please enter the password ");
      scanf("%d",&answer);
      if(answer == 1)
         printf("correct");
         break;
   }

}
```

Comment: To have two (or more) statements after an `if`, you need to put the statements in braces: `{ }`

Comment: damn my dumb book doesn't mention "To have two (or more) statements after an if, you need to put the statements in braces: { }"

Comment: Problem solved! Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: LOL, maybe you should get a new book :) Anyways, glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

You're not doing what you thing you are doing inside the for loop. Without braces, an if statement will only cover one statement so no matter if the condition inside the if statement is true or false you will hit the break.

This is what your code is doing now:

```
for( ; ; )
{
    printf("please enter the password ");
    scanf("%d",&answer);
    if(answer == 1)
    {
        printf("correct");
    }
    break;
}
```

What you actually want is this:

```
for( ; ; )
{
    printf("please enter the password ");
    scanf("%d",&answer);
    if(answer == 1)
    {
        printf("correct");
        break;
    }

}
```

So even though it *looks* like the if in your code handles both statements, it does not. There's even a famous example of a bug like this going into production in [Apple's goto fail](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2014/02/24/anatomy-of-a-goto-fail-apples-ssl-bug-explained-plus-an-unofficial-patch/). It's something to be aware of which is why some coding styles always require brackets around ifs, else ifs, and elses even if it's just one statement.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to place additional braces:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int answer = 0;
    while (answer != 0)
    {
        printf("please enter the password ");
        scanf("%d",&answer);
        if(answer == 1) {
            printf("correct");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```